# How to code a constaint that contains an integral in java &cplex?

Tags: java, math, constraints, cplex, mixed-integer-programming

I started Java programming 2 months ago. I don't know how to code a constraint in the Java+Cplex library. This constraint contains an integral. Does Java contain an integral library already and I'll need just to enter the bounds or is there another method for this?

```
 //constraints
            IloLinearNumExpr capacity= cplex.linearIntExpr();
            capacity.addTerms();
// the constraint is I-integral(P)dt+ Ps(t1-t0)>Ilow
```

Comment: *"Does Java contain an integral library"* No.

Comment: @Olivier is there any method to do so?

Comment: Why don't you just read the documentation of CPLEX?

Comment: @Olivier that's what Im gonna do, Thank you.